# Create table from model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, owin

I use OWIN and identity for authorization and authentication in my project after first hit the tables created.

Now I need to add some additional tables.
so I created my custom model called Author.

Now from the created model I need to create table using migration.

But before I need to create `dbset<Author>`. So my question is where do I create `dbset<Author>` property?

Here is the code:

```
public class LibraryDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Authors> Authors;
}

public class Authors
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

when I run this command:

```
add-migration
```

I get this:

```
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

public partial class addAuthor : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

I get add migration empty.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one place where you are going to place DbSet properties and that is you class that is inheriting DbContext.

Comment: that what I do. after I do add migration I get empty migration file

Comment: You are missing the code for database configuration. You need to apply that migration to somewhere and you are not doing that.